# New to JavaScript - why won't my function execute?

Tags: javascript, function, call

I'm taking an intro JavaScript course and I'm following all of the directions but the function is not executing. I have viewed many "JavaScript won't execute" questions on StackOverflow and none of them contained an answer that would solve my problem.

Here is the HTML header:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Monroe Public Library</title>
<link href="mplstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="random.js"></script>
<script>
/*
The showImg() function displays a random image from the 0.jpg through 9.jpg files. The
random image is designed to thwart hackers attempting to enter the library records data
base by requiring visual confirmation
*/

function showImg() {
    var imgNumber = randomInteger(9);
    // Return a random number from 0 to 9
    document.write("<img 'src=" + imgNumber + ".jpg' alt='' />");
}

</script>
</head>
```

Here is the portion of my HTML calling the function. It's supposed to call four times in order to output the HTML string five times and show five of the number images on the webpage.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
   <th>Username</th>
   <td><input size="20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>    
   <th>Password</th>
   <td><input type="password" size="20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>As a final security check, enter the 5 numbers 
   you see displayed below.</td>
   <td><input size="6" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="2" class="center">
   <input type="button" value="View Library Records" />
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="2" class="center">
   <script>showImg();showImg();showImg();showImg();showImg();</script>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

When I open the page it doesn't output anything; just stays the way I wrote it with the script element and function call. The table cell simply shows up as empty. I've put a message box into the function to see if it even enters it at all, and it does, but the message box only appears once (no matter how many times I call the function).

The JavaScript file (random.js) as well as the HTML is all provided and working so I only included the relevant sections.

Comment: <script>showImg();showImg();showImg();showImg();showImg();</script> what is this?

Comment: Do you understand how `document.write` works?

Comment: Is there anything in browser console? An error? I assume the randomInteger function is included in the random.js include.

Comment: @user2181397 This is me attempting to call the function five times; I'm just starting so I wouldn't be surprised if it's way off but I couldn't find anything that says otherwise.

I know there are better ways to call a function multiple times (with a loop) but because it's the first section in the class, the instructions say in this instance to simply type it out five times.

Comment: @j08691: It's being ran *before* the page is finished loading, so it will work and not erase the page.  It's not the best practice, but it *should* work here.

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/javascript/?hl=en). Then you could have at least found out that the function is indeed called.

Comment: can you please put this code in jsfiddle

Comment: @j08691 I very well might not. I previously wrote `return ""<img 'src=imgNumber.jpg' alt=' />"` but another student said that he used document.write() so I decided to try that instead.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I suppose I should've been clearer and not insinuated that it was the problem. I meant for the OP to understand how it actually functions, and that it's usually not the best method to choose.

Comment: @j08691: Fair enough :)

Comment: @j08691 What would be the best way for me to achieve this? The directions on the assignment only say to output that specific string; it doesn't specify how they want us doing it.

Comment: There's a million ways to skin a cat in JavaScript (as you'll learn), and here's one http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/g7h7kwyh/

Comment: @j08691 great thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is related, but you have `"<img 'src="` instead of `"<img src='"`

Other than that, defining

```
function randomInteger(rng) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * rng);
}
```

and changing your `document.write` line to

```
document.write("<b>" + imgNumber + ".jpg</b> ");
```

worked fine for me.

Comment: This was exactly my issue - incorrect quotes. Once I fixed the quotes, the code worked properly.  Thanks Ian

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
 document.write("<img 'src=" + imgNumber + ".jpg' alt='' />");
```

Has an apostrophe out of place. It should be

```
 document.write("<img src='" + imgNumber + ".jpg' alt='' />");
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
   <th>Username</th>
   <td><input size="20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>    
   <th>Password</th>
   <td><input type="password" size="20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>As a final security check, enter the 5 numbers 
   you see displayed below.</td>
   <td><input size="6" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="2" class="center">
   <input type="button" value="View Library Records" />
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="2" class="center">
     <script>
     function showImg() {
        var imgNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        document.write("<img src='" + imgNumber + ".jpg' alt='' />");
     }
     showImg();showImg();showImg();showImg();showImg();
     </script>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have previous programming and web experience (believe it or not), and this is clearly better. I think my instructor just wants us to have practice importing from a file and calling a function declared in the head. Oh well.

Comment: I only moved the script inline to get it to run in this sandbox, not part of what I was showing...

Comment: Okay that's what I figured; just wasn't positive so I included it in my comment. :)